# Proof of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider Rolle's theorem. 
Suppose $f(M)=\max\{f(x): x \in[a,b]\}$ with $f(M) \neq f(a)$. Now 
we will prove $f'(M)=0$. 
$\lim_{x \to M^+} \frac{f(x)-f(M)}{x-M} \leq 0$ since $f(x) \leq f(M)$ and $x>M$. 
Again $\lim_{x \to M^-} \frac{f(x)-f(M)}{x-M} \geq 0$ as both numerator and denominator $<0$. Since $f'(M)$ exist, $f'(M)=0$.

Is there any flaw in the above arguments?

Comment: Since $f(a) = f(b)$ is part of the hypothesis it is worth mentioning that $M \in (a,b)$ so that both one-sided limits make sense, but that is really just a nitpick. Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct but doesn't discuss the general case since it's possible that $f$ has a minimum and not a maximum in a point different of $a$ . So let's give a complete proof.

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[a,b]$ then it's a  bounded function and attains the two extremum $m$ and $M$.

- If $m=M$ then $f$ is constant and the desired  result is clear.
- If $m<M$ then one of these two value is different of $f(a)=f(b)$ and WLOG *(the other case is similar)* let $f(a)\ne M$ and the rest of the proof is similar to your work.

Answer (score 1):

The only flaw in this is that isn't this actually not Rolle's theorem, but actually Fermat's theorem on stationary points.

Rolle's theorem says if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f(a) = f(b)$ then $\exists c \in (a,b) \text{ with } f'(c) = 0$.

Fermat's theorem says if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $c$ a local maximum in $(a,b)$ then $f'(c)=0$ and has an identical proof to the one you just showed.

Although I do agree that one way to prove Rolle's theorem is to say "a continuous function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b], a \neq b$ with $f(a) = f(b)$ has, WLOG, a maximum at $c \in (a,b)$ and then by Fermat's theorem $f'(c) = 0$